# How to make CLASS slide down/appear on scroll up?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, menu, sticky

I am building a WordPress website with Padma theme.
I would like to set up a sticky menu to slide down/appear/stick in place when the page is scrolled down.

I have added a menu that can be seen on page load to begin with. When the page is scrolled down, this menu disappears upwards and beyond the top of the window.
I have set up a second menu as a class, so that as the page scrolls down by a certain amount it can slide down and remain in the original menu's place and stick to the top of the page.

Having looked into doing this, I used the coding from W3Schools. The problem is, this coding uses ID's, whereas Padma will only let me set the wrapper up as a CLASS.

CSS code:

```
.navbar-slide-down {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: -100px;
```

}

The Javascript code I was going to use:

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar-slide-down").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar-slide-down").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

But obviously the Javascript uses `getElementById` but I need it to refer to `navbar-slide-down` as a 'class' instead...

How would I change this so that the script referred to the CLASS instead of an ID?

Comment: Try using ``querySelectorAll(".class")`` and iterating through them using ``forEach`` and checking whatever for each of the element that have that class,

Comment: Do you have an example you can show me? I can change the querySelector, its the forEach bit I'm not too sure on...